# Images in table view are getting disappear after scrolling for logn time

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, ios7

My application have `UITableView`. I am using custom cell that have lable and `UIImage`. Its working fine for normal scrolling. But if I scroll that for long time, then images get disappeared. And there was `error = 24 (to many open files) in console`.

From Google, I got that instead of using `UIImage imageNamed`, used `initWithContentOfFile`. But that dose not work. Please help.

---

**Edit** Adding code written in comments:

This is the code used for adding the image to the cell:

```
UIImage *img =[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sms_icon" ofType:@"png"]]; [cell.img setImage:img]; [img release];
```

---

Comment: Post your code. Specifically whatever it is you are doing in cellForRowAtIndexPath: Also please explain what you mean by "after long time".

Comment: How u add images on cell. Pls provide code written in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: I have used below line to set image.           [cell.img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sms_icon.png"]]; But that did not work so i used following code:
                UIImage *img =[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sms_icon" ofType:@"png"]];
                [cell.img setImage:img];
                [img release];

Comment: use first method - don't add the ".png" extension. imageNamed is much better in your case because it has an internal caching mechanism.

Comment: I will try for it. Another is after scrolling for 5 to 7 minutes, when I click on did select row at index path, it gives me crash with following reason.Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle

Comment: Removing png is worked for me. Thank you. Can you explain me what is difference when using png and without using png.

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation says](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_19)

The method (+ImageNamed:) looks in the system caches for an image object with the specified name and returns that object if it exists. If a matching image object is not already in the cache, this method loads the image data from the specified file, caches it, and then returns the resulting object.

On a device running iOS 4 or later, the behavior is identical if the device’s screen has a scale of 1.0. If the screen has a scale of 2.0, this method first searches for an image file with the same filename with an @2x suffix appended to it. For example, if the file’s name is button, it first searches for button@2x. If it finds a 2x, it loads that image and sets the scale property of the returned UIImage object to 2.0. Otherwise, it loads the unmodified filename and sets the scale property to 1.0.
On iOS 4 and later, if the file is in PNG format, it is not necessary to specify the .PNG filename extension. Prior to iOS 4, you must specify the filename extension.If you have an image file that will only be displayed once and wish to ensure that it does not get added to the system’s cache, you should instead create your image using imageWithContentsOfFile:. ***This will keep your single-use image out of the system image cache, potentially improving the memory use characteristics of your app.***

Comment: I Tried to use imageWithContentsOfFile insted of imagednamed. But I am getting following error and images disappear from screen.<Error>: ImageIO: CGImageReadCreateDataWithMappedFile  'open' failed '/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0-64/Applications/D891AC4C-F865-472C-AC5D-AE607AE7D985/eVoice_US.app/eVoice_voicemail_icon@2x.png'
          error = 24 (Too many open files)

Comment: Result is same for both imagedname also.

Comment: Need to trace the code. Let me know how you have coded for cellfor Indexpath